# fsockopen is returning an error even if the server im trying to reach is online?

Tags: php, minecraft

im using fsockopen below:

```
$socket = fsockopen("uberminecraft.com", 25565, $errno, $errstr, 1);

return ($errno === 0);
```

Now this should return either false or true if the server is up or not. I know this server is definty up yet i still keep getting an error

```
Warning: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to uberminecraft.com:25565 (Connection timed out)
```

Comment: I'd double check a few things before assuming PHP is the culprit.  Make sure your firewall is ok with PHP making outbound connections on that port and double check that the receiving server is listening on that port.

Comment: You'd only get true/false if the TCP syn packets actually got through and either result in a open connection, or a 'connection refused' rejection. Timed out usually indicates that something's blocking the packets and dropping them on the floor, e.g. a firewall.

Answer (score 1):

You have set a timeout of 1 second, is this intentional? Do you know whether the server is able to provide a response fast enough? Have you tried setting a higher timeout?

Also you might want to look at php.net for how to check whether the connection was made.

Answer (score 0):

You must change fsockopen function as follow

$socket = fsockopen("uberminecraft.com", 25565, $errno, $errstr, 30);

Still you are getting same error. please tell to your host provider to open 25565 port.

Thanks